# Typescript object with known properties dynamically

Tags: typescript

I have a situation where I need to dynamically use an object property. Typescript doesn't like when I do that..

The situation is similar as the one described above.

How can I type check the `Enum[val]` or `foo` variable?

```
enum Enum {
    VAR1 = "A",
    VAR2 = "B",
}

const foo = ["VAR1", "VAR2"];
foo.forEach(val => {
    const a = Enum[val]; // Typescript doesn't like it (val implicitly has 'any' type...)
    const b = Enum[val as any]; // This is "OK", but I use "any", which I'm trying to avoid.
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const foo: (keyof typeof Enum)[] = ["VAR1", "VAR2"];
```